# Unable to raise VALUE_ERROR when mandatory values are null

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

employeeid, employeename, and jobid are the mandatory NOT NULL fields in my table. If any of them are null, I want to raise a VALUE_ERROR exception, though I am not getting the results expected.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_employee(
    p_employeeid IN employees.employeeid%TYPE,
    p_employeename IN employees.employeename%TYPE,
    p_phone IN employees.phone%TYPE,
    p_jobid IN employees.jobid%TYPE,
    p_salary IN employees.salary%TYPE,
    p_managerid IN employees.managerid%TYPE,
    p_departmentid IN employees.departmentid%TYPE

) 

IS

BEGIN
    IF p_employeeid = NULL THEN
        RAISE VALUE_ERROR;

    ELSE IF p_employeename = NULL THEN
        RAISE VALUE_ERROR;

    ELSE IF p_jobid = NULL THEN
        RAISE VALUE_ERROR;

    ELSE
    INSERT INTO employees (employeeid, employeename, phone, jobid, salary, managerid, departmentid)
    VALUES(p_employeeid, p_employeename, p_phone, p_jobid, p_salary, p_managerid, p_departmentid);

    END IF;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN VALUE_ERROR THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (06502, 'VALUE_ERROR');

END;
```

**I get this error:**
*Errors: PROCEDURE INSERT_EMPLOYEE Line/Col: 30/1 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EXCEPTION" when expecting one of the following: ( begin case declare end exit for goto if loop mod null pragma raise return select update while with    << continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge json_exists json_value json_query json_object json_array Line/Col: 34/4 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: end not pragma final instantiable persistable order overriding static member constructor map*

Answer (score 0):

That's wrong, obviously, for several reasons.

- comparing a value to NULL should be with `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`, not by using equality sign `=`
- the first argument of the RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR should be a number between `-20001` and `-20999` (though, as you put it, VALUE_ERROR is a predefined exception, you don't have to re-raise it)

I shortened it (didn't feel like typing that much in vain):

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_employee(
  2    p_employeeid     IN               NUMBER,
  3    p_employeename   IN               NUMBER,
  4    p_jobid          IN               NUMBER
  5  )IS
  6  BEGIN
  7    IF p_employeeid IS NULL THEN
  8      RAISE value_error;
  9    ELSIF p_employeename IS NULL THEN
 10      RAISE value_error;
 11    ELSIF p_jobid IS NULL THEN
 12      RAISE value_error;
 13    ELSE
 14      NULL;
 15    END IF;
 16  EXCEPTION
 17    WHEN value_error THEN
 18      raise_application_error(-20001,'This is a VALUE_ERROR');
 19  END;
 20  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
SQL> EXEC insert_employee(1,2,NULL);
BEGIN insert_employee(1,2,NULL); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20001: This is a VALUE_ERROR
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.INSERT_EMPLOYEE", line 18
ORA-06512: at line 1


SQL> EXEC insert_employee(1,2,3);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```